# MySQL query igual a um valor ou outro

Tags: mysql

Estou com uma duvida em uma *query* do MySQL.

Eu tenho esta *query*

```sql
select cor from cores where cor in('verde','vermelho');
```

O problema é que eu quero o verde, e Caso se não tenha verde eu quero o vermelho. mas não os 2 resultados.

Eu não posso usar o `LIMIT 1`, porque isto esta dentro de uma *subquery* mais complexa e o MySQL não deixa usar `LIMIT` em *subquery*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ao invés do operador `IN`, você pode usar o `CASE` para verificar se um registro existe. É como fazer um `IF` em uma linguagem estruturada.

Veja um exemplo:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
     WHEN EXISTS(select cor from cores where cor = 'verde') THEN 'verde'
     ELSE (select cor from cores where cor = 'vermelho')
  END,
  CASE 
     WHEN EXISTS(select cor from cores where cor = 'azul') THEN 'azul'
     WHEN EXISTS(select cor from cores where cor = 'verde') THEN 'verde'
     ELSE (select cor from cores where cor = 'vermelho')
  END
```

Alternativamente, você pode usar a função `COALESCE`, que vai retornar o primeiro parâmetro que não seja nulo, estabelecendo assim uma ordem de prioridade.

Veja o exemplo:

```
select
  COALESCE(
    (select cor from cores where cor = 'azul'),
    (select cor from cores where cor = 'verde'),
    (select cor from cores where cor = 'vermelho')
  )
```

Veja também o [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/518740/3) com os exemplos funcionais.

Comment: Não sabia desse SQLFiddle, muito útil, obrigado :)

Comment: Eu fiquei em dúvida no exemplo do `CASE`, ele vai executar os dois `CASE`s ou ele tenta executar um e, caso não retorne nada, ele executa o outro?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Isso mesmo, ele deveria funcionar como um `if/else`: se existe 'azul', então retorna 'azul, senão faz o select por 'vermelho'.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Mas note que você você ter vários 'WHEN' diferentes. Vou editar a resposta para exemplificar isso.

Comment: Valeu a query que eu estava usando era um `inner join on` e com o coalesce ficou perfeito. Usei da seguinte forma: `on coalesce((RIGHT(upper(c.filename), CHAR_LENGTH(b.value) + 4) = concat(b.value, '.PSD')), (RIGHT(upper(c.filename), CHAR_LENGTH(b.value) + 4) = concat(b.value, '.JPG')))`

Comment: Eu entendi o `WHEN`, o que eu não entendi foi o `CASE`. Tipo, tem dois `CASE`s no `SELECT`, mas a consulta sempre vai executar os dois `CASE`s ou só quando um não tiver retorno? Entendeu o que eu quis perguntar?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar *Acho* que agora entendi. No exemplo que coloquei o select vai executar os dois *cases*, seriam como duas colunas distintas e independentes.

Comment: Era exatamente isso, obrigado.